# Conditionally Coloring Cells in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, background-color

I am working on optimizing a report that I have in SSRS and am having some difficulty with a line of code. Essentially what I want is for a check to be made if the cell is blank, or if it has data. If it is blank I need the cell color to change to red. If it has data I need it to stay transparent. Here is what I have written.

```
=iif(Isnothing(Fields!MedServices.Value)= "True", "Red", iif(Isnothing(Fields!MedServices.Value)= "False", "Transparent"))
```

When I go to save this though I get the below error:

> The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘MedServices’ contains
>   an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart'
>   of 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object,
>   FalsePart As Object) As Object'.

I know this must be a stupid error on my part with parenthesis, but I cannot figure out where I have made the error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsNothing()` function returns a boolean data type, true or false it is a valid expression for the `IIF()` function.

Try:

```
=iif(Isnothing(Fields!MedServices.Value) or Fields!MedServices.Value="",
"Red", "Transparent")
```

Comment: So that got rid of the error when saving, but the cell didn't color. I think you have pointed me in the right direction though to figure out the rest of this. Thank you very much!